# PHP open a newtab on a URL POST

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have looked at about 100 questions and can't find anything like this, I apologize if it has!

I am POSTing in PHP on a wordpress site:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
a bunch of stuff that all works

postUrl =  'https://services/?parameters'; //this works too!

}

get_header();
?>
<div stuff that all displays correctly>
<div class="form-row">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</div>   
<? php 
  $servicePost = wp_remote_post( esc_url_raw($postUrl));  //This is the problem URL
 echo "<script>window.location=$servicePost;<script>";
 ?>
```

On submit, it runs a bunch of API calls, all work, and it even makes the post in $servicePost. But the service at that URL $postURL, at a good POST, should auto redirect to a URL (post to it, and it returns a "302" with a "Location: https:ActualLaunchURL).
I need to redirect that Service to a new tab in the browser.

RIght now, i think what is happening, isthe POST populates as the $servicePost makes the actual call, and by the time it gets to the JS window.open its not a POST anymore, and doesn't hit the service with window.open.

Question: can I make a POST, and open a new tab as the call runs, inside that <\script> window.open?

I also tried:

```
<\script type="text/javascript">  
var form = document.createElement('FORM');
form.method='POST';
form.action = $ampssoData;
form.target = '_blank'; 
document.body.appendChild(form)
form.submit();
</script>
```

In the HTML after the Submit, this doesn't even post though, so I

Comment: No. The result will always be returned to the opened window.

Comment: The technical answer above should be couched by: "anything is possible" with the messaging API and some hacking.

Comment: @RandyCasburn so if the code works in the sense, that POST, actual is correct (my service is updated), its just not opening the link in the response...Maybe  Ican turn the window.open in to a submit()?

Comment: Still isn't going to achieve your goal of "response in new tab". In order to do that, you would have to 1. open the new window, 2. send the form data to the new window (`postMessage()`), 3. inject some JS into the new window that can submit the form data 4. submit the form data from within the new window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found how to: 
Make a POST in a PHP file for Wordpress,
that opens a new tab, 
POSTing the PHP URL Variable to the service

This is what it was:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
a bunch of stuff that all works

postUrl =  'https://services/?parameters'; //this works too!

}

get_header();
?>
<div stuff that all displays correctly>
<?php if: 
<div class="form-row">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</div>   
<? php 
$servicePost = wp_remote_post( esc_url_raw($postUrl));  //This is the problem URL
echo "<script>window.location=$servicePost;<script>";
?>
```

And here is the correct bottom portion:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
a bunch of stuff that all works

postUrl =  'https://services/?parameters'; //this works too!

}

get_header();
?>
<div stuff that all displays correctly>
<div class="form-row">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</div>   
<?php else: ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
                     function openWindowWithPost(url){
                         var form = document.createElement('form');
                         form.method='POST';
                         form.action = url;
                         form.target = '_blank';
                     document.body.appendChild(form);
                     form.submit();
                 }
                 </script>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                 openWindowWithPost("<?php echo $postUrl; ?>");
                 </script>
```

Which takes the data from the PHP variable, and makes the call in the HTML part of the PHP file. It triggered the pop-up blocker the first time, but otherwise worked!
if someone could tell me how to not trigger that, if possible, that would be cool!